# Why does the PowerPC Compiler emit a clclr instruction before calling a function?

Tags: disassembly, powerpc

I disassemble my own written code in C to PowerPC assembly, and I can't understand why `crclr` occurrs before the call to the `printf` function.

**C code**

```
int main()
{
     int a, b, c;
     a = 10;
     b = 2;
     c = a * b;
     printf("%d", c);
     return 0;
}
```

**PowerPC assembly code**

```
stwu r1, -0x10(r1)
mflr r0
stw r0, 0x14(r1)
lis r3, unk_38@h
addi r3, r3, unk_38@l
li r4, 0x14
crclr 4*cr1+eq
bl printf
li r3, 0
lwz r0, 0x14(r1)
mtlr r0
addi r1, r1, 0x10
blr

unk_38:
   .byte 0x25 # %
   .byte 0x64 # d
```

Could anyone please tell me why?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be an artifact of compiler optimization. Note the `li r4,0x14` instruction - the compiler optimizes your `2*10` calculation and loads the result, `20`, into `r4` directly. However, doing the calculation would modify some status bits, which the `li` doesn't, so the compiler tries to do the same modification using `crclr`, and the optimizer isn't smart enough to realize that this isn't really neccesary when it precedes a function call.